# How to delete local empty git branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I created a local empty branch with:

```
mkdir test
cd test
git checkout -b branch_local
```

I am not able to delete it with:

```
git branch -D branch_local
```

I get

```
error: Cannot delete branch 'branch_local' checked out at 'D:/test'
```

Please advise.

Comment: You need to check out a different branch first, but are you trying to delete the *repository* or the *branch*?

Comment: Are you trying to delete the whole repository or the branch? Your question and the context is very ambiguous.

Comment: The commands you listed do not create or delete a repository. They operate on branches. Read more about the Git concepts in the [Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the question. It is a branch creation and deletion, not repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove your repository and keep the files in it, you can remove the `.git/` directory in `test/`. WARNING: This will destroy your history!

If you want to remove the repository and the files, you can remove the directory `test/`. WARNING: This will destroy the history AND the files!

If you want to destroy the new branch and switch to another one (this is what I think you want to do), you need to check out that branch first.
If it exists, you run `git checkout <branch_name> && git branch -D branch_local`. If the other branch doesn't exist, you add the `-b` flag: `git checkout -b <branch_name> && git branch -D branch_local` WARNING: The history in `branch_local` will be lost unless you keep the hash of the commit and prevent any garbage collections.

If you want to remove the branch without checking out a new one, you can remove the file `.git/refs/heads/branch_local`. Git will still think that you have this branch checked out since that name is in the `.git/HEAD` file, and this file is needed for the repository to be valid.

Note that if you created the new branch from an initial commit, the file `.git/refs/heads/branch_local` won't exist, and nor will the branch.
The name is only the name of the branch to be created if you make a commit, and this name is stored in the `.git/HEAD` file, which contains the line

```
ref: refs/heads/branch_local
```

Thus you can edit the file directly, or do it using the git commands above.

In summary, there has to be a name of a branch in the `.git/HEAD` file or the repository is invalid, regardless of whether the branch actually exists.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't find a file: .git/refs/heads/branch_local. So I removed the ref: refs/heads/branch_local from .git/HEAD. I am wondering if there is a command to delete a branch without checking out a new one.

Comment: I think you disregarded the last paragraph: there has to be a name of a branch in that file. If you run `git status` in the repository, you should get an error message now. I'd suggest you put that line back, but replace the branch name with another one.

Comment: Please re-read my previous comment. There was a line in the HEAD file which I deleted in order to delete the local branch. However, I could not find a file that was named after the local branch about which you had mentioned in para 4, sentence 1.

Answer (score 4):

Check out on different branch before deleting the branch to be deleted.
For example :

STEP 1: git checkout master

STEP 2: git branch -D branch_local

branch_local is the name of branch to be deleted.

Comment: STEP 1 will fail if the pwd is not connected to a repo.